# What is the minimum All-Star score(s)?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

What are the minimum scores in All-Stars for each difficulty? I want to collect all of the alt trophies, but I want an easy to figure out if I beat All-Star as a character (besides going to the gallery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the main component of score in all-star mode is damage dealt, there is no theoretical minimum or maximum.

Comment: Is there an average?

Comment: Well yeah, but it's based on how much damage you tend to do before KOing people, so there's no real way anyone but you can figure it out.